# How to fix high px deq slave session stats in Oracle RDS

Tags: amazon-rds, parallelism, oracle-19c, waits, slow-query

We are seeing some high percentage of "px deq slave session stats" waits in our Production database.(this maintained on AWS RDS). Due to which outage is happening many times

from searching we found that this salve session is mainly created when an parallel execution is happened

But we are not sure what is the Query which is using this parallels execution

Checking the Active sessions we can able to find

Query : `select sql_id,count(*) from v$active_session_history where event like '%PX Deq: Slave Session Stats%' group by sql_id;`

OUTPUT
[image]

Any possible solutions?
Thanks in advance